# run apt-get with proxy in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, proxy, environment-variables, aptitude

I am behind a proxy an i need to install something via `apt-get`.

The best I came with is this

```
ARG PROXY
ENV http_proxy=$PROXY
ENV https_proxy=$PROXY
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install ...
ENV http_proxy=
ENV https_proxy=
```

The thing is that I need to unset those environment variables afterwards.

Any idea how to do it in less then 5 layers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [build-time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) (–build-arg).

This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the RUN instruction of the Dockerfile. Also, these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like ENV values do.

So, your `Dockerfile` is only 3 lines:

```
ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install ...
```

And you just need to define build-time variables `http_proxy` and/or `https_proxy` during image building:

```
$ docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port> --build-arg https_proxy=https://<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port> .
```

Comment: http_proxy and https_proxy are predefined build args, no need to write ARG for them. see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#predefined-args  +1 because the proxy can be changed without busting the docker cache -- but be careful, wget, curl, ... also use this variables

Answer (score 3):

Using also [build time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) (–build-arg), you can add at the beginning (before `apt-get update`) [apt proxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server#Method_2:_Use_as_a_proxy_to_APT) configuration:

```
...
ARG APT_PROXY
RUN echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"$APT_PROXY\";" | tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install ...
...
```

This is useful in the scenario you want to only cache packages from APT repositories

Comment: Why do you use `tee` here instead of redirection?

Comment: good: this configures the proxy for apt only -- but be aware the docker cache is busted when the proxy changes